# max(), min() with raw_input and different outcomes in python

Tags: python, max, min

I am having a trouble finding the max and the min with this code, it can't calculate them, it's just throwing inexact results when inputting data, for example, I do not know why setting the raw input to be int rather than str the code doesn't print the correct result, though max or min calculates right when used solely with a list, and why letting it to be to remain str the code does calculates right, but just for sometimes, sometimes it throws something gross!
what is the different between setting the raw inout into int or remain as a string when relating to max() or min(), why there is such difference?
and why int object is not iterable in for loop?

```
while True:

    x = raw_input('')
    if x == 'd':
        break
    try:
        v = x # or v = int(x)
    except:
        continue

    numbers = []

    numbers.append(v)


print max(numbers)
print min(numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while True: 
    # ...
    numbers = []
```

`numbers` is assigned to a new empty list in every loop iteration. The values that you thought it stores are all lost. It should be put outside the loop instead:

```
numbers = []   # Move it here

while True:  
    # ...
    numbers.append(v)
```